# Class associations and lists

Tags: c#, .net, mapping

I have a little C# problem. I have two classes ClassA and ClassB defined in this way :

```
public class ClassA
{
    private ClassB b;
    ClassB B;
    {
        get { return b; }
        set { b = value; }
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    /* some stuff */
}
```

As you can see, ClassA has an instance of ClassB.

The thing is, from a list of ClassA instances, I want to access to a list of the corresponding ClassB instances. I suppose it would look like this:

```
IList<ClassA> listA = ...;
IList<ClassB> listB = listA.???.B;
```

The solution is probably obvious but I can't figure it out by myself.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Which c# version are you running? Do you, for example have access to LINQ? If so, see my answer.

Comment: I do have access to LINQ, and I'm working with .NET 3.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use LINQ to do

```
IList<ClassB> listB = listA.Select(a => a.B).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using List.ConvertAll():

```
List<ClassA> listA = ...;
List<ClassB> listB = listA.ConvertAll(item => item.B);
```

Comment: Just a little nitpicking but ConvertAll is just a standard method of the List<T> class not an extension method :D

Answer (score 1):

You could easily do this with LINQ to Objects in one of the following ways:

```
var instancesOfClassB = from a in listOfClassA
                        select a.B;

var instancesOfClassB = listOfClassA.Select(a => a.B);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
IList<B> listB = listA.ConvertAll(a => a.B);
```

which is simple and says what it does.